# Why rollback Access database table contents after update

Tags: ms-access

I wrote a program in vb.net 2012 that use a MS Access 2003 database to store some things. When I run my app and do add new or update or delete and ... on the table contents, that changes is take effect in my database (I open the database file in MS Access and see that all changes have taken place).

When I stop the app running and run it again I see that all changes have been rolled back and no changes are stored.

Can somebody help me solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you did not commit changes. Please post code so we can see the transaction process.

Comment: I have created a data source by wizard and named it PackageDataSet then bind it PackageDataSetBindingSource and create SettingTableAdapter that setting is my table name .

Comment: Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MouseHook.InstallHook()
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'PackageDataSet.Setting' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.SettingTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PackageDataSet.Setting)
    End Sub

Comment: Even with out using my application when i manually change the fields of table records in office , after running my app, all changes like delete a record , addnew a record, changing a field value & ... goes rolled back and it seems that nothings was happen